# How can I convert this select duplicates statement to an update?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, duplicates

I have this select statement that finds duplicates in my table based on certain criteria.

The select is:

```
select  DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE, BIRTHDATE, count(*)
  from work
  group by  DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE, BIRTHDATE
  having count(*) > 1
```

I want to convert this to an update that appends a letter into a field in my table. For example,

```
UPDATE [WORK] SET BAD_CODES = BAD_CODES  & 'D'
```

Any ideas on how to make this update statement?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do it, but I'm not terribly familiar with Access:

```
UPDATE [WORK] 
SET BAD_CODES = BAD_CODES  & 'D'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE, BIRTHDATE, COUNT(*)
              FROM work b
              WHERE [WORK].DIVISION = b.DIVISION
                AND [WORK].FIPS_COUNTY_CODE = b.FIPS_COUNTY_CODE
                AND [WORK].LAST = b.LAST
                AND [WORK].SUFFIX = b.SUFFIX
                AND [WORK].FIRST = b.FIRST
                AND [WORK].TITLE = b.TITLE
                AND [WORK].BIRTHDATE = b.BIRTHDATE
              GROUP BY DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE, BIRTHDATE
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
             )
```

This should be equivalent, but is useful if you wanted to use a value from your subquery in the update:

```
UPDATE T 
SET    BAD_CODES = BAD_CODES  & 'D'
FROM   work AS T 
JOIN (SELECT DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE, BIRTHDATE, COUNT(*)
      FROM work                      
      GROUP BY DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE, BIRTHDATE
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      ) AS S
  ON  T.DIVISION = S.DIVISION
  AND T.FIPS_COUNTY_CODE = S.FIPS_COUNTY_CODE
  AND T.LAST = S.LAST
  AND T.SUFFIX = S.SUFFIX
  AND T.FIRST = S.FIRST
  AND T.TITLE = S.TITLE
  AND T.BIRTHDATE = S.BIRTHDATE
```

Comment: It doesn't throw an error for this, but it seems to be taking a LONG time to run. It always seems to stick at 0% process. There are 1.3 million records, but most queries run within 15s (the basic select I made runs in about 10 seconds). Any ideas why it's so slow?

Comment: That's a fair chunk of records for Access, I'd expect an `UPDATE` to take considerably longer than a `SELECT` but not sure how much longer is reasonable. You could try the 2nd query and see if it performs better, I would think they'd be roughly the same.

Comment: It shouldn't take TOO long. There are only 609 duplicate records being updated. I will try the second query.

Comment: It says it is missing an operator. I'll look for it hold up. Let me know if you know where it is.

Comment: I didn't update the table aliases when I copied the join criteria, updated now.

Comment: Did moving the `SET` to the bottom make it work, or is the error the query not updateable one that you mentioned in your new question?

Comment: I had things moved around and I no longer get a syntax error. It errors out on running it now, and after doing some digging online I figured out that I need to create a temporary table for it. But I honestly don't have a clue.

Comment: I have a primary key (my auto increment ID), but would not including it in this statement cause this error for me?

Comment: The primary key shouldn't be an issue, sadly I don't know Access enough to be helpful there.